# Access PostgreSQL running in Docker container in Vagrant

Tags: postgresql, docker, vagrant, iptables

I have a Vagrant box in which I have a Docker container that runs PostgreSQL. The container is the official one found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)

I want to be able to connect to Postgres from the host (i.e outside of Vagrant) using psql but can't get it to work. (Get a "could not connect"-error). I have added a port forward in my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5432
```

But I'm guessing this is not enough since the Docker container has its own IP (172.17.0.2)? My thought was that I would put a iptable rule on the box that forwards all requests to the Vagrant box on port 5432 to destination 172.17.0.2:5432 like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5432
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But I still can't make it work. Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add `iptables` rule externally. vagrant port forwarding will take care itself.

Check below points:

1. check your PostgreSQL port in vagrant instance. if port is bind with particular IP then you have to give IP in `Vagrantfile` to forward that IP and port. Like

> guest_ip (string) - The guest IP to bind the forwarded port to. If
>   this is not set, the port will go to every IP interface. By default,
>   this is empty.

2. Similarly, you can give host IP also

> host_ip (string) - The IP on the host you want to bind the forwarded
>   port to. If not specified, it will be bound to every IP. By default,
>   this is empty.

If everything ok and you can connect using command like:

```
psql -p 5432 -d db_name -U user -h localhost
```

Don't forget to add `-h` with hostname or ip. Also see These answer:

1.[unable to connect to forwarded port over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220359/unable-to-connect-to-forwarded-port-over-ssh)

2.[Accessing to a remote PostgreSQL server using port forwarding to another machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/790412/accessing-to-a-remote-postgresql-server-using-port-forwarding-to-another-machine)

Comment: Ah, silly me. I had missed that I needed to explicitly add `-h localhost`, thought that was the default. When I added that it worked. Thanks!